# Change variable only once with if statement

Tags: expression, after-effects

Not sure if overflow is strictly the right place, but it is technically coding.

I'm trying to write an expression in Adobe After Effects to toggle a checkbox once and only once in an if statement.

I have an object with a null parent. The null object is rotating. When the null object gets to a certain rotation I want a checkbox to turn on and stay on

This is what I tried but obviously doesn't work

```
t=0;
yrot=transform.rotation;

if(yrot==0){
    t=1;
}

if(t==1){
    active;
}
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you could add a second variable of type `boolean` to check if you already entered the if statement.

I would recommend to add something like `boolean done = false;`(I'm not sure about the syntax...)

and in the if-statement:

```
if (t == 1 && !done) {
    active;
    done = true;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the null object continues to rotate past 0° (0° is the trigger point) so the statement is only true for a second

Comment: oh sorry I didn't get that first. Could you probably check the state of the checkbox instead of the boolean variable? something like `if (t == 1 && !checkbox.isActive())`?

Comment: Basically what's happening is the statement is true for a second and t=1, then the statement is false and t=0. When t==1 it needs to stay equal to one

Comment: Btw I think AE expressions are based on JS

Comment: do you have any possibility to check the current checkboxstate? because this way the value of t would only matter one time. If the checkbox is checked and you get the state (true) you can combine t==1 and !state with a logic & and it just will enter the statement if the checkbox is not checked

Comment: OH YEAH!! That's so obvious! xD

Comment: Actually theres another problem now. if (active) {t=1;} turns it on straight away

Comment: :D
try: if (active && yroot == 0) { t=1;}?